# duplicate icon when installing IOS Ad hoc distribution application

Tags: iphone, ios

[image: screenshot]

Please see the above picture.
I build and adhoc-distribution application of IOS. When installing, there are 2 icon appeared .
When complete,there is only one.Application then work properly

Is that really a problem.Anybody can explain to me why ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You likely changed the bundle identifier in the ad hoc build.